# Encapsulation: why the name keySet in java

Tags: java, dictionary, encapsulation

In java to get all the keys in a map we can use the method `keySet`. But I was wondering why the method name is not just `keys`? isn't the name `Set` leaks details about the implementation?

As per my understanding Java is statically typed language and having types in names makes no sense at all. The calling code anyways must have the correct interface type. If we assume that this strategy is correct then every method must have types prefixed to them which doesn't makes any sense. I think @JBNizet stated correctly in his comment the reason behind the choice.

Comment: because, it return `Set`

Comment: And also because the old Hashtable already had a method named keys() returning an Enumeration. So another name had to be used for the new method returning a Set.

Comment: @JBNizet I think yours is the correct answer, it was not by choice.

Comment: It's not the correct answer. keySet(), as mentioned by others, doesn't break any encapsulation. I just think they would probably have chosen keys() (as they did with values()) if they could have.

Comment: @JBNizet as stated earlier its not a good naming convention anyways, It adds type to names.

Comment: @Ravi according to your reasoning every method name should be prefixed by type but its not true and this convention is not followed throughout in java see for example `values` method in `Map` interface.

Comment: Again, this is a matter of preference and taste. Having a type in a method name is not inherently bad. It can provide meaningful information about the method, especially when using auto-completion. It can also help disambiguating methods (think intValue(), longValue(),doubleValue() in Number, for example). And often, the type also is the most precise name to specify what a method returns. Think Path.getFileSystem(), for example.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you but then I see lack of consistency. But yes we cannot do anything with that because there are some backward issues etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering why the method name is not just `keys`

Like so many things in modern Java, backwards compatibility got in the way a bit: `keys()` was already taken (by [java.util.Hashtable.keys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#keys()), and that class should still be able to implement `Map`), so they had to choose something else.

> Doesn't the name Set leaks details about the implementation ?

No, it does not. The `Map` interface already specifies that there cannot be duplicate keys. So the collection of keys is a `Set` by definition. And `Set` is still an interface for which there can be different implementations.

Answer (score 4):

> isn't the name Set leaks details about the implementation?

1) `Set` is an interface.
If for example, the method were named `keyHashSet()`, it would not be a good idea 
as  `HashSet` is an implementation of `Set`.

But `keySet()` is fine because having as return type an interface that defines a specific contract and using a name that conveys this specific contract in the method name is a valid way to program by interface and to be able to return any implementation of `Set` in a clean way.

2) Besides choosing in the `Map` interface  the  `keys()` method name rather than `keySet()` is not possible either.
As @JB Nizet suggests in its comment, a  `keys()` method is already defined in a JDK collection class : `Enumeration<K> keys()`.
It is declared in the `Dictionary` class that `HashTable` inherits from :

```
public class Hashtable<K,V>  extends Dictionary<K,V>...{
```

But this method : `Enumeration<K> keys();` doesn't return a `Set`.
So `HashTable` that is both a `Dictionary` and a `Map` :

```
public class Hashtable<K,V>  extends Dictionary<K,V>  implements Map<K,V>,
```

has to implement one method to return the keys in an `Enumeration` form but also another one to return them in a `Set` form.
A distinct naming is so required to distinguish them

You may also note that `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet()` also defined in the `Map` interface follows the same naming logic while no other hierarchy of `HashTable` defines a `entries()` method.
It is probably to be consistent.

Comment: Java is statically typed language and having types in names makes no sense then. The calling code anyways must have the correct interface type.

Comment: @CodeYogi: the name is just because `keys` was already taken.

Comment: @Thilo yes and that is the correct answer, if given a choice between `keys` and `keySet`, the first one is better, right?

Comment: Yes. But the other one is not super-terrible either. And it certainly does not dictate a certain implementation (which is what the question is mostly concerned about). Might as well get worked up about `keySet` vs `getKeySet`. Or the fact that neither name nor type make it clear that the returned set is a *view*, not a snapshot, or whether it is mutable or not.

Comment: @Thilo: Heh, good point. The "Set" part of the name really isn't the biggest issue with it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> isn't the name `Set` leaks details about the implementation?

The declaration `Set<K> keySet()` doesn't tell us any more about the 
*implementation* than `Set<K> keys()` would. In both cases, we know that the method returns a `Set`. `Set` is an interface, not a concrete class.

Whether it's a good idea to include that in the name is a matter of style (personally, no, I don't think it is; but reasonable people can differ). But doing so doesn't tell us anything about the *implementation* that we wouldn't know anyway.